# What's wrong with my solution?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Question: 
"If the rate of change of $y$ with respect to $x$ is $5$ and $x$ is changing at $3$ units per second, then $y$ is changing faster than $x$."

My attempt :
$dy/dx = 5$ (given)$.......1$

$dx/dt = 3..........2$ (given)

Multiplying $1$ by $2$ we get 
$dy/dt = 15$

So we can conclude that $y$ is changing at $15$ units per second. Hence we can say that $y$ is changing faster than $x$. So we can say that the statement is True.

I know this is a really easy and my solution is totally correct but at the back of my text it's given that the statement is false. I really don't know where  I'm going wrong. Am I  missing something here. Kindly validate.

Comment: Looks correct..

Comment: Well done!  +1...

Comment: @Dr.MV I was asking this because at the back of my text it's mentioned that the statement is false.

Comment: Maybe the answer in the book was written for an earlier edition and they changed the wording of the problem without changing the answer. I have seen other cases where the textbook's "answer" is a correct answer for a question slightly different than the question that is asked, so it's not just this book.

Comment: If you didn't have the part about $x$ changing $3$ units per second, the statement would be "false" (which in my experience is the true/false-question code for "not always true") because if $x$ is not changing at the moment when you make the observation, then $y$ also is not changing, so it is certainly not changing _faster._

Comment: @user109256  5 times faster, correct

Answer (score 1):

So you have ${\rm d}y = 5 {\rm d}x$ and ${\rm d}x = 3 {\rm d}t$ when dealing with small (infinitesimal) changes.

Correctly you stated then $${\rm d}y = 5 \cdot (3 {\rm d}t) = 15 {\rm d} t$$

Stated differently, if you have $\dot{x} = 3$ and $\dot{y}=15$ then $$ \frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}x} = \frac{\dot{y}}{\dot{x}} = \frac{15}{3} = 5 $$

The speed of $x$ is 3 and the speed of $y$ is 5, no doubt about it.